# multiple markers on google map in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Sorry I am new to asp.net and I want to make an web application where I need to show google map with multiple markers. I have searched on internet and found some source but all the sources are same. when I use those sources I find some syntax error and I am unable to resolve them. please help anyone.
here is code that I am used on 'web form with master page'.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="AlHadi_Assosiates.About" %>
```

```
    var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
             {
                 "title": '<%# Eval("title") %>',
             "lat": '<%# Eval("lat") %>',
             "lng": '<%# Eval("lng") %>',
             "description": '<%# Eval("description") %>'
         }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.44, 78.79),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            //  marker:true
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvCanvas"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvCanvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
<h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
<h3>Your application description page.</h3>
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

and here is syntax error:

I will be thankful for guidance

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the same code, I think you mean the repeater control in javascript tags, That appears like syntax error but it works normal when u run it. Just build like that and run.